# Вывести имена объектов Unity, C Sharp

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, list, ui

У меня есть 80 объектов и каждый имеет свое имя в public string на одном скрипте
Необходимо вывести все объекты, которые были кликнуты и в другом окне, те, что не были кликнуты. Логика думал будет такая. Создам скрипт, где лист или массив, будет принимать имена объектов и через UI.Text буду их выводить

Прием имен

```
[SerializeField] private Text LeftText;

public static string[] NameObj;
public static List<string> NameObj = new List<string>();

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NameObj.Count; i++)
    {
        //LeftText.text += TClickObj.ObjName + "\n ";
        LeftText.text = $"\n" + NameObj[i];
        //LeftText.text = $"{NameObj[i]}\n";
        //Console.WriteLine(NameObj[i]);
    }

    LeftText.fontSize = 30;
}
//public static void GetName(string Name)
//{
    //for(int i = 0; i < NameObj.Length; i++)
    //{
    //    NameObj.Add(Name);
    //}
    //NameObj.Add(Name);
//}
```

И скрипт, где клик с именами

```
public string ObjName;


public void OnMouseDown()
{     
    if (!one)
    {
        TCore.CC++;
        one = true;
        //TTextControl.GetName(ObjName);
        TTextControl.NameObj.Add(ObjName);

    }
}
```

Comment: Где вопрос или где ошибка?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, собственно текстовое поле ничего не выводит, ошибок при запуске проекта нет
Толи не правильно добавляю в лист имена, толи не верно вывод данных делаю, хотя массив и вывод текста - классика, с виду верно, на деле не работает

Comment: А с чего вдруг должно что-то отображаться? В безымянном классе (где список NameObj) вывод идет только один раз - в методе Start(); Этот метод в MonoBehaviour вызывается "атоматически" лишь один раз для объекта.
Вам необходимо после изменений списков еще вызывать какой-нибудь метод вывода/обновления информации

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, а возможно сделать как-то список так, чтобы он пополнялся и только в конце один раз его вывести?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, кто будет юзать. На объект, который нужно кликнуть:

```
[SerializeField] private string _ObjName;
public string Name { get => _ObjName; }
[SerializeField] private bool _isClicked;
public bool isClicked { get => _isClicked; }
 
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    _isClicked = true;
}
```

Далее создаем 2 текстовых поля, добавляем их через инспектор и в НОВОМ скрипте:

```
public class Visualizer : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    [SerializeField] private Text LeftText;
    [SerializeField] private Text RightText;
    private Naming[] _AllNamingObjects => FindObjectsOfType<Naming>();
    private List<string> ObjectsText = new List<string>();
    private void Start()
    {
        LeftText.fontSize = 30;
        LeftText.text += $"Найдено:\n ";
        for (int i = 0; i < _AllNamingObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_AllNamingObjects[i].isClicked)
            {
                LeftText.text += _AllNamingObjects[i].Name + $"\n";
            }
 
        }
 
        RightText.fontSize = 30;
        RightText.text += $"Не найдено:\n ";
        for (int i = 0; i < _AllNamingObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!(_AllNamingObjects[i].isClicked))
            {
                RightText.text += _AllNamingObjects[i].Name + $"\n";
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```